# Tiny "Color Code" problem

Tags: colors

I'm a student and recently I'm making a website in order to share the course with others
And I got a problem:
I'm trying to express the "Course Heat Degree" by color
(now all the color is bule in the following picture)

now I get a **course_heat_num** from the server but I have no idea how to use it cause I want the
"**cool color**"(like #cc00ff) represent small course_heat_num and "**warm color**"(like #ff0000) represent the big number

I don't know the function or the variation in the chang from the cool color to the warm color(BTW:**not** from #000000 to #FFFFFF)
[image]
Hope Someone can help!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. How do I distinguish between a hot and cool color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at HSL colours in the [CSS3 Colour Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#hsl-color).

It allows you to express colours as Hue, Saturation, and Lightness instead of RGB values. In your example, blue would be `hsl(0, 100%, 50%)` but red would be `hsl(249, 100%, 50%)`. You can vary between 0 and 249 for the hue parameter.

To get an idea of what the colours look like, try the [HSL Color Picker](http://hslpicker.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature), here are a number of ways for you to go.

Pick a technique, and calculate the proper color, it should be nice.